# Implementations of Lasso in Python and R?

Tags: r, python, scikit-learn, lasso

I would like to have a overview of the implementations of LASSO in Python and R. I am not well versed in R and it seems there are several different implementations.

In python, as far as I know, the most common implementation of LASSO is provided by the [Library SKlearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html). In this library the implementation is given by *"coordinate descent"* algorithm.

How about R?

Comment: I would guess `glmnet` is common in R because so many people followed Hastie's books and online courses.  Using the `caret` package is also popular as it allows many different forecasting methods to be used with relatively small changes to inputs and outputs

Comment: It seems that (due to references of this package) glmnet also uses the coordinate descent: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v039i05

Comment: caret I was not able to find. In a code I founding the load of the lars package (?)